# Can the next page be designated as a self-modal area in the modal−div area?

Tags: html, django, authentication, modal-dialog, self

Inside the template, the login foam zone was mapped inside the modal pill.
If normal login is normal, it is normally moved to home.However, if it is not registered or a positor occurs Outside the Modal Div area, mark the foam with respect to the custom form.I would like to call a Page which is remanuded to the Modal Div area in the event of an unregistered user and a photoelectricity.
It can be a difficult question because it is a translator.
Can I fix this problem?

My sauce is below me. Additional posts can be posted if necessary.

**mysite.urls.py**

```
    from django.conf.urls import url,include
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**view.py**

```
from blog.models import Post
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

UserModel = get_user_model()

# --TemplateView
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'mysite/home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        User = get_user_model()
        context= super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['post_like'] = Post.objects.all()
        return context

class AboutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'mysite/about.html'


class UserCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'registration/register.html'
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('register_done')

class UserCreateDoneTV(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'registration/register_done.html'

class LoginRequiredMixin(object):
    @classmethod
    def as_view(cls,**initkwargs):
        view = super(LoginRequiredMixin, cls).as_view(**initkwargs)
        return login_required(view)
```

base.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">


/* login modal */
     jQuery(function($){
    $('#loginmodalbutton').click(function(){
        $('#myModal').find('.modal-content').load("{% url 'login' %}");
        $('#myModal').modal();
        });
    });
</script>
<!---- base top menu -->>
<header>
    <div class="w3-top w3-text-orange w3-animate-opacity" style="z-index:100;">
        <div class="w3-bar" id="myNavbar">
            <a style="text-decoration:none" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-right w3-hover-red" id="loginmodalbutton">로그인</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

registration/login.html

```
<div class="w3-card-4 w3-text-black w3-animate-top" style="max-width:auto">
    <div class="w3-center">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-xlarge w3-transparent w3-display-topright" title="창닫기">×</span>
        <img src='' alt="회원 로그인" class="w3-margin-top">
        <br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <form class="w3-container" action="{% url 'login' %}" target="#myModal" method="post" id="login_form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% if form.errors %}
        <p class="errornote">비밀번호는 영문자를 포함한 8자리 이상으로 입력하세요.</p>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="w3-section">
            <label for="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}"><b>아이디</b></label>
            <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-margin-bottom" type="text" id="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}" name="{{ form.username.html_name }}" placeholder="아이디를 입력하세요.">
            <label for="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}"><b>비밀번호</b></label>
            <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="password" id="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}" name="{{ form.password.html_name }}" placeholder="비밀번호를 입력하세요.">
            <input type="submit" class="w3-button w3-block w3-green w3-section w3-padding" value="로그인"/>
        </div>
        <input class="w3-check w3-margin-top" type="checkbox" checked="checked"> 아이디 저장

        <div class="w3-container w3-border-top w3-padding-16 w3-light-grey">
            <button onclick="document.getElementById('modal').style.display='none'" type="button" class="w3-button w3-red">Cancel</button>
            <span class="w3-right w3-padding w3-hide-small"><a href="#">아이디와 비밀번호를 잊어 버리셨나요? </a></span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```